# Validar select dentro del Submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estimados tengo esta implenetacion en teroia ya funciona pero tengo el evento del select en una funcion aparte y el evento del submit en otra, lo que no consigo es validar o impedir que el select se envie al dar click al botton submit estan la funciones sepradas pero no se como pasar la referencia de la validacion del select al evento submit para que lo valide antes de enviar si no ha seleccionado un valor. espero se entienda. Gracias

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import { useForm } from "../../hooks/useForm";
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { startLoginEmailPassword } from "../../redux/actions/auth";
export const FormLogin = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { loading } = useSelector((state) => state.ui);

  const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const { email, password } = formValues;

  let users = [
    { value: "1", label: "Usuario 1" },
    { value: "2", label: "Usuario 2" },
  ];

  users.unshift({
    value: '0',
    label: "[ Seleccione una opicón ]",
  });

  const [captchaValido, cambiarCaptchaValido] = useState(null);
  //const [usuarioValido, cambiarUsuarioValido] = useState(false);
  const [errorUsuario, setErrorUsuario] = useState(null);
  const [errorPassword, setErrorPasword] = useState(null);
  const [errorSelect, seterrorSelect] = useState('');

  const handleSelectChange = () => (e) => {
    let val = e.target.value;
    localStorage.setItem("item_id", `${val}`);
    if (!val) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Error!',
        text: 'No ha seleccionado ninguna opción',
        icon: 'error',
        confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
      })
    } else if (val === '0') {
      return false;
    }
  };

  const captcha = useRef(null);
  const onCaptcha = () => {
    if (captcha.current.getValue()) {
      cambiarCaptchaValido(true);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleSelectChange();
    if (captcha.current.getValue()) {
      //cambiarUsuarioValido(true);
      cambiarCaptchaValido(true);
    } else {
      //cambiarUsuarioValido(false);
      cambiarCaptchaValido(false);
    }

    if (!email.trim()) {
      setErrorUsuario("El campo usuario (email) es requerido");
      return;
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email)) {
      setErrorUsuario("Ingrese un email valido.");
      return;
    }

    if (!password.trim()) {
      setErrorPasword("El campo password es requerido");
      return;
    } else if (
      !/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])([A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]|[^ ]){8,15}$/.test(
        password
      )
    ) {
      setErrorPasword("Ingrese un formato Valido");
      return;
    }

    setErrorUsuario(null);
    setErrorPasword(null);
    seterrorSelect(null);

    dispatch(startLoginEmailPassword(email, password));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group mb-2">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              autoComplete="off"
              value={email}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              onBlur={() => setErrorUsuario(null)}
            />
            {errorUsuario ? (
              <span className="text-danger">{errorUsuario}</span>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div className="form-group mb-2">
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              autoComplete="off"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={password}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              onBlur={() => setErrorPasword(null)}
            />
            {errorPassword ? (
              <span className="text-danger">{errorPassword}</span>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div className="form-group mb-2">
            <select
              className="form-select"
              name="options"
              onChange={handleSelectChange()}
              onBlur={() => seterrorSelect("")}
            >
              {users.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
                    {item.label}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
            {errorSelect ? (
              <span className="text-danger">{errorSelect}</span>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div className="text-center mb-2">
            <a href="/#" className="text-decoration-none text-secondary forgot">
              Olvidé mi contraseña
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="recaptcha">
            <ReCAPTCHA
              ref={captcha}
              sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              onChange={onCaptcha}
            />
          </div>
          {captchaValido === false && (
            <div className="text-danger">Por favor acepta el captcha</div>
          )}
          <div className="d-grid gap-2">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn bg-button block subtitle"
              disabled={loading}
            >
              INGRESAR
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div className="text-center mt-2">
          <a href="/#" className="text-decoration questions">
            PREGUNTAS FRECUENTES
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimados realize unas modificaciones, ya consegui la validacion que no envie si el campo es 0 o null, el problema ahora se presenta que nesecito guardar el valor del value en el localstorage y me retorna undefined, por favor alguien me pude dar una mano, dejo la modificacion.

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import { useForm } from "../../hooks/useForm";
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { startLoginEmailPassword } from "../../redux/actions/auth";
export const FormLogin = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { loading } = useSelector((state) => state.ui);

  const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    options:""
  });
  const { email, password, options } = formValues;

  let users = [
    { value: "1", label: "Usuario 1" },
    { value: "2", label: "Usuario 2" },
  ];

  users.unshift({
    value: "",
    label: "[ Seleccione una opicón ]",
  });


  const [captchaValido, cambiarCaptchaValido] = useState(null);
  //const [usuarioValido, cambiarUsuarioValido] = useState(false);
  const [errorUsuario, setErrorUsuario] = useState(null);
  const [errorPassword, setErrorPasword] = useState(null);
  const [errorSelect, seterrorSelect] = useState("");

  /* const handleSelectChange = () => (e) => {
    let val = e.target.value;
    localStorage.setItem("item_id", `${val}`);
    if (!val) console.log("No ha seleccionado ninguna opción");
    else console.log(`El valor seleccionado es ${val}`);
  }; */

 
  const captcha = useRef(null);
  const onCaptcha = () => {
    if (captcha.current.getValue()) {
      cambiarCaptchaValido(true);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let optForm = document.forms["form"]["options"].selectedIndex;
    if( optForm === null || optForm === 0 ) {
      seterrorSelect("Debe seleccionar una opción en el campo");
      return false;                 
    } else {
      let val = e.target.value;
      localStorage.setItem("item_id", JSON.stringify(val));
    }
    
    if (captcha.current.getValue()) {
      //cambiarUsuarioValido(true);
      cambiarCaptchaValido(true);
    } else {
      //cambiarUsuarioValido(false);
      cambiarCaptchaValido(false);
    }

    if (!email.trim()) {
      setErrorUsuario("El campo usuario (email) es requerido");
      return;
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email)) {
      setErrorUsuario("Ingrese un email valido.");
      return;
    }

    if (!password.trim()) {
      setErrorPasword("El campo password es requerido");
      return;
    } else if (
      !/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])([A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]|[^ ]){8,15}$/.test(
        password
      )
    ) {
      setErrorPasword("Ingrese un formato Valido");
      return;
    }

    setErrorUsuario(null);
    setErrorPasword(null);
    seterrorSelect(null);

    dispatch(startLoginEmailPassword(email, password));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form name="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group mb-2">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              autoComplete="off"
              value={email}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              onBlur={() => setErrorUsuario(null)}
            />
            {errorUsuario ? (
              <span className="text-danger">{errorUsuario}</span>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div className="form-group mb-2">
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              autoComplete="off"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={password}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              onBlur={() => setErrorPasword(null)}
            />
            {errorPassword ? (
              <span className="text-danger">{errorPassword}</span>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div className="form-group mb-2">
            <select
              className="form-select"
              name="options"
              value={options}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              onBlur={() => seterrorSelect("")}
            >
              {users.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
                    {item.label}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
            {errorSelect ? (
              <span className="text-danger">{errorSelect}</span>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div className="text-center mb-2">
            <a href="/#" className="text-decoration-none text-secondary forgot">
              Olvidé mi contraseña
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="recaptcha">
            <ReCAPTCHA
              ref={captcha}
              sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              onChange={onCaptcha}
            />
          </div>
          {captchaValido === false && (
            <div className="text-danger">Por favor acepta el captcha</div>
          )}
          <div className="d-grid gap-2">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn bg-button block subtitle"
              disabled={loading}
            >
              INGRESAR
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div className="text-center mt-2">
          <a href="/#" className="text-decoration questions">
            PREGUNTAS FRECUENTES
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```